# what is the name of this body for post for a webService

Tags: android, iphone, ios, web-services

I have sent json requests before [iOS to server],

now I have to send a post request to a server with this body:

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

testabc
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date"

2001-12-1
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profession"

bbbb
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"

adfasfasf
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="state"

NSW
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

Australia
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postcode"

1111
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quantity"

0
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expirydate"

2012-1-1
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="batchnum"

aaaa
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product"

test product
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quantity"

3
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expirydate"

2012-4-1
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="batchnum"

aaaa-2
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product"

test product -2
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="territory"

A112
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="territorymanager"

murtaza
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="rogz.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\vincent.yang\Pictures\rogz.jpg*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

and this header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: nutr.orcha.net
Content-Length: 12160
```

so the question is:
what is the name of this kind of post body?

is not json offcourse, but what would it be?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Mime is just another standard of organising data.